# Copying OS Release and Package Metadata in minimalistic Docker images with FROM scratch

Tags: docker, containers

Without OS release or package metadata vulnerability scanners, like Trivy, can't detect vulnerabilities in a container image. So, I'm trying to figure out how to include that information when an image uses FROM scratch to keep the image small.

The problem I'm currently running into is when I copy the os-release information by itself, it works to detect the OS. But as soon as I add another COPY line to include OS package metadata the scanner no longer detects the OS.

```
FROM arm64v8/debian:9.8-slim as base

FROM scratch
COPY --from=base /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status
COPY --from=base /etc/os-release /etc/os-release
```

Any ideas on why the first COPY command is canceling out the second?

**Update**: After experimenting with different distros, I found that this issue only occurs when the OS release and package information matches the host.

For example, if I use the `alpine: latest` and update the os release path to `/etc/alpine-release` Trivy is able to detect the file. However, if I use ubuntu:latest with the path of `/etc/os-release` the OS isn't detected with Trivy, which makes me think Docker is mounting volumnes over these file paths.

Comment: Do you need these files in the image to **work** (not to run some scanners on it)? If you don't, why not create two images from different bases (base passed as arg), use small from scratch for actual runtime and large based on some image for checking? Then you won't pollute real image and won't jump through hoops to make a scanner work.

Comment: `arm64v8/alpine` is already extremely small (less than 5MB), isn't it good for your needs?

Comment: That's a good point. Perhaps the FROM scratch isn't necessary.